# How to resolve locale issue with `jack.import.type.policy`?

Tags: java, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2, android-jack-and-jill

I am building an app which **must** use Java 8 libraries. To  enable source compatibility I added following to app's build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "SOME_APP"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // enable Jack
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
//...
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Upon building solution I get following errors:

```
Error:com.android.sched.util.config.PropertyIdException: Property 'jack.import.type.policy' (in -D option): The value must be {keep-fırst,faıl} (case insensitive) but is 'keep-first'
Error:com.android.sched.util.codec.ParsingException: The value must be {keep-fırst,faıl} (case insensitive) but is 'keep-first'
```

As you can see this error is caused by Turkish `İ i I ı` chars. Someone else got this error and this is the [issue ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227091). This issue is marked for resolve in  the future release but, due to importance of project I cannot wait for this future release.

There is a suggested solution in issue ticket:

> A tricky solution that i made:
>   Created run configurations for all jack related tasks in gradle (almost 9), and update VM Options part with -Duser.language=en

I tried to apply this by editing VM Options

[image]

and adding `-Duser.language=en` to studio.exe.vmoptions file.

Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue, I get same errors whenever I try to build project.

- Is my current configuration right?
- Is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution. This behaviour is caused by *language of non-unicode programs* settings in Windows. I had *Turkish* as language of non-unicode programs. After changing it to *English* issue resolved.

[EDIT] The following solution is valid for *Android Studio running on Windows*

To change, navigate to Control Panel -> Region and Language. Click on Administrative tab. Click on Change system locale and select English. Click apply and restart if necessary.

[image]

Comment: I could not find "Region and Language". I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: @Limitlessisa "Region and Language" is accessible from Windows Control Panel. This solution is valid for android Studio running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  @raidensan

Change computer language, solved problem. (Using Windows8)

- Denetim Masası -> Dil -> Dil ekle ->ingilizce
- Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language

[image]